# SnapView in a Magazine reader (Windows 8)

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am developing a Magazine reader. The users first chooses a magazine, then a issue and the issue content is shown as a series of images (1 image = 1 page) in a FlipView.

How would you display the issue detail in SnapView? Showing the image for a page does not make much sense, is not readebla.e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show list of images for the specific issue in a blured list like a film ribbon. 
Also you can add a tip, "In snapped mode images cant be viewed well, please change the view mode"

By the way, i completely agree with Serg Rogovtsev.

Answer (score 0):

Your page should be not image but composition of text and illustrations. Then you may reflow it to any screen size and orientation, *including* SnapView (which is fine approximation of sidebar in page layout).

Comment: it is the only format the magazine has (and it works for them in iPad app), I have no choice

Comment: Then it makes no sense making snapped version of your application.

Comment: It is. But it hasn't to be fully functional.